# What is the equivalent of a normal subgroup in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

In group theory, the quotient group G/H is a group only if H is a normal subgroup because you can be sure the group operations are well defined.

Now does linear algebra have something similar? For example, the linear map of the quotient space T(V/U, W) where U is a subspace of V. Is this a well defined linear transformation or does the subspace U need to meet some criteria for the linear map to be well defined?

Comment: Since everything is abelian, every subspace is "normal" by default.

Answer (score 2):

For any subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$, the quotient $V/U$ has the structure of a vector space. So yeah, in this sense every subspace of a vector space is *normal*.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it fully answers to your question, but note that we have a short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow U\longrightarrow V\longrightarrow V/U\longrightarrow 0,$$
and the $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor is left exact, so we deduce an exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(V/U,W)  \longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(U,W), $$
which shows the linear maps from $V/U$ to any vector space $W$  are obtained from the  linear maps from $V$ to $W$ which vanish on $U$.